# X11 doesn't recognize certain windows

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, window-manager, window

While trying to stream a game on Discord, I noticed that it didn't recognize the game.

After looking further into this it seems that X11 seems to display the window but not actually recognize it when listing windows via `xlsclients -l`

I'm not sure how to fix this seeing as Google/DDG is of no help and kept displaying results regarding the OS Windows, any help is highly appreciated.